# Dark theme How to pass fonction with styled component

Tags: styled-components

i am trying to add inside styled component const a switch but i get lost

EX:

```
 background-color: ${({ open }) => (open ? "#ffb900" : "#333")};
```

i want to add my theme fonction for get color switch with #ffb900

`${({ theme }) => theme.hamburger}`
but in proper way :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using [styled-theming](https://jamie.build/styled-theming.html) for theming.